# How to filter array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

Here is my array of two values .

```
let dataList = ["x","y","z","a","b"]
let data2= {
  x:{hide:true},
  y:{hide:true},
  z:{},
  a:{}
}
```

here is my trying code:

```
let filters = dataList.filter(item=>Object.keys(data2).includes(item))
```

I want to filter dataList based data2 - hide:true . For example, if values object property hide:true inside data2 , key will be removed .

expected output :

```
["z","a"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it is a simple as this

```js
let dataList = ["x","y","z","a","b"]
let data2= {
  x:{hide:true},
  y:{hide:true},
  z:{},
  a:{}
}

let filters = dataList.filter(item=> data2[item] && !data2[item].hide)

console.log(filters)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the key exists on `data2` and check for `hide` to be `true`

`dataList.filter(item => data2[item] && !data2[item].hide )`

Comment: You beat me by 30 seconds, because of  my snippet ;)

Comment: yeah, no snippets for me :)